Doxysphinx creates the wrong path in rst files
When doxysphinx makes rst files based on doxygen output files, it creates
the wrong path. For instance, in index.rst the same word is repeated as '<namespaces_namespaces>'. It should be just 'namespaces'.
.. toctree::
    :caption: Main Page
    :maxdepth: 2
    :hidden:

    Related Pages <pages>
    Topics <topics>
    Namespaces <namespaces_namespaces>

I'm stuck with this issue.

Issue reported: https://github.com/boschglobal/doxysphinx/issues/154
